# Install guest additons to ubuntu 12.4 virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to install guest additons to ubuntu virtual machine . In Settings->Storage I see VBoxGuestAdditions.iso , but dont see anything in /media/cdrom? How can I install guest additions in ubuntu 12.4?

Answer (score 0):

Start the virtual machine. Then go into the virtualbox menu and click

```
Devices -> Install Guest Additions (Host+D)
```

This will open a popup menu to install Guest Additions.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it via terminal inside the guest:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```